# Matlab plot showing data size as frequence by letters

Tags: python, plot

[image]A student found an exercise online asking to draw a plot of DNA sequences using Python Matlab. The Data is on the left side and the expected plot on the right. There are 15 columns and 10 rows. Each column echoes the X-axis on the right. The rows are the frequency of letters which reflected by the size of letters on the plot.

I am neither a Matlab user nor a biologist, I have never seen this plot before. Can anyone advise what it is called and how to plot it in Python?
The data can be generated by the code below:

```
df=np.random.choice(list('atcg'),  size=(10,15))
```

Comment: FYI, it's called a [sequence logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo).

Comment: If you just want to plot in Python, please do not add a matlab tag. If you want to use Matlab, knowing that it is sequence logo like @jfaccioni said, https://es.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html explains how to use it in Matlab.

Comment: Follow the comments and the page https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html, I tried to use seqlogo, but got an error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Actually all functions under seqlogo are not callable, I tried ```from seqlogo import *```

Comment: @SHendricks the provided links are for the Matlab programming language, writing `from seqlogo import *` is Python.